# Flash preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I've designed a circular preloader that get filled according the percentage of loaded frames.
Everything works great with a frame or two of content aside preloader. When I add the all site with a billion of frames and movie clips, the preloader won't work properly and I'm getting really bored with this because I spent like 4 days trying to understand what is wrong.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the problem I hope that the pro's can give me an explanation of what is going wrong. Thank you all.

Code from preloader:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loading);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loading(e:ProgressEvent):void{
    var porcent:Number = Math.floor((e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal) * 100);
    porcent_txt.text = String(porcent) + "%";
    loader.gotoAndPlay(porcent);
}

function loaded(e:Event):void{
    this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loading);
    this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
    gotoAndStop("enter");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give more info on what's not working properly? What are you seeing? Is your preloader not showing up for ages before popping up at 95% or something?

Comment: I've uploaded an image can you please take a look at it? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, thank you very much for your help it was very helpfull

The code was ok
the preloader movieclip was ok also
The problem was on a layer with some text in fact I don't know why this problem happend my guess is that it must be related with deeper problems in my project... don't know

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your library items are not exported to the first frame.
A normal flash file should have nothing except the preloader on the first frame. Don`t use any other classes except the one you need for the preloader in the first frame.

[image: see the first and second frame here]

Comment: Preloader code goes into first actions frame. 
Preloader can be seen in the second layer were a button "enter" is placed. The rest of the website is placed in otherlayer at the third frame.


When I simulate the download the preloader with little content an image or two on a separate layer (third frame) everything works as expected but when I load all the layers at frame 3 the preloader doesn't work at all...

Comment: Ok guys I found out what the problem was... some text object at the bottom layer was giving me troubles I 've remover the text and now everything is running perfect! Crazy...

Comment: @FCC-PT glad to see you got the problem fixed. you should submit it as an answer and you can mark your question as resolved